# How to query contract input (address) using Etherscan's API?

Tags: etherscan, addresses, query

How would I query using their API? Below doesn't seem to want to work, I'm querying for canMint() where it takes in address[] and returns a Boolean.

https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0xc25B19Fa4a0bb8Ad16B2E164DfBb344012F29A50&data=0xbeb9716d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000035Fb85AF34adbdD00850392dfE3251283bAf1b75

All I'm getting is the `execution reverted` error. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query the method of the smart contract actually. you should query the events/logs of the smart contracts

If you are trying to query the canMint() function executions. you need to query the events that were emitted while executing the canMint() method.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply, I've got one more question (bear with, I'm coming from tezos, new to eth smart contracts). If I were to query https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0xc25B19Fa4a0bb8Ad16B2E164DfBb344012F29A50&data=0x22d8dc23, how could I decode the response? It's hashed out, and I'm confused on how I could get the actual values. Thanks.

Comment: this response seems like a tranasaction data . you can try decoding it with abi-decoder- https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

Comment: Got it, thanks for the guidance!